# Отображение кириллицы в CLion

Tags: c++, кириллица, clion

Нужна помощь: не отображается кириллица в терминале CLion. Вот так выглядит надпись "Привет, Мир!":

> ╨Я╤А╨╕╨▓╨╡╤В, ╨Ь╨╕╤А!

Вот что будет с кодировкой `windows-1251`:

> ╧ЁштхЄ, ╠шЁ!

Comment: UTF8 можете попробовать?

Comment: Везде стоит кодировка UTF8.

Comment: Открываем [декодер текста](https://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/) и видим, что кодировка текста у вас - CP866. Поэтому вам надо разобраться с вашими кодировками, где-то что-то поломалось

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Почему так происходит?

CLion по дефолту использует `UTF-8` для хранения файлов с исходным кодом. Строка `"Привет, Мир!"` будет представлять собой последовательность (в файле с исходником):

```
D0 9F D1 80 D0 B8 D0 B2 D0 B5 D1 82 2C 20 D0 9C D0 B8 D1 80 21
```

Как видите, на 12 символов исходной строки, получили 21 байт (т.к. кириллические символы занимают больше одного байта).

Компилятор GCC по умолчанию читает исходники в кодировке `UTF8`, если не указать другую через ключ `-finput-charset`. Таким образом эта последовательность байтов в неизменном виде сохранится в исполняемый файл.

При запуске программы на исполнение, CLion использует стандартный `cmd.exe`, который по умолчанию скорей всего у вас работает в кодировке `CP866`. В которой наша последовательность байтов будет отображена как:

```
╨Я╤А╨╕╨▓╨╡╤В, ╨Ь╨╕╤А!
```

(что вы и видите в терминале CLion)

---

### Что делать?

**Вариант 1**

Сменить кодировку файла на `IBM866` (то же, что и `CP866`) (настройки - File Encodings) (сам файл перекодировать, если в нем уже был текст на русском). Теперь кириллица будет сохраняться в файле с исходным текстом в кодировке `CP866` (один байт на символ), в том же виде попадать в исполняемый файл и нормально отображаться в консоли CLion. Разумеется, использовать `CP866` в 19-м году, без особых на то оснований, некультурно. Кроме того придется ограничить себя символами из `CP866`.

**Вариант 2**

Вставить в начало свой программы:

```
system("chcp 65001");
```

или (потребует `#include <windows.h>`):

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
```

Консоль переключится в `UTF-8`, все будет отображаться как надо. Но только при использовании низкоуровневых операций вывода типа `puts("Привет, Мир!");`. Если выводить через `std::cout`, то возможен вывод типа `��ривет, Мир!`. Это связано с тем, что функция Windows API для вывода в консоль ожидает увидеть в каждом вызове законченную строку. И если оператор `basic_ostream<char>::operator<<(char*)` для символа 'П' выполнит два API вызова (с `D0` и `9F`), то они не сольются в одну букву 'П', а будут интерпретированы и отображены как два разных символа (`��`).

---

### Предостережение

При использовании `UTF-8` в своей программе, например при хранении в `std::string`, следует помнить, что операции над строками могут дать не очевидные результаты (т.к. один символ теперь может занимать от 1 до 4 байтов).

Кроме вывода, аналогичные проблемы ожидают и при вводе из `std::cin`. Таким образом, единственным прозрачным решением для Windows (даже десятки), пока остается использование латиницы.

Comment: Уточню по варианту 1, в настройках encoding не нашел CP866, только IBM866...

Comment: @Andreyua ага, точно, жетбрейнцы решили так обозвать. Вроде ещё встречается вариант обозначения csibm866. Обновил.

Comment: Для себя решил пока проблему так: буду выносить все насущные :) строковые константы в отдельный хидер с кодировкой IBM866. Пока так, дальше посмотрим. С меня 50 баллов через 14 часов (раньше система не позволяет).

Comment: @Andreyua да, тоже так делал. Есть ещё вариант - конвертировать уже в своей программе utf8 в cp866 перед выводом, но тоже как-то не очень смотрится.

Comment: Еще было бы неплохо дополнить ответ функциями перекодировки текста с UTF-8 в IBM866 ... И по необходимости их использовать...

Answer (score 2):

Для Clion:

Cygwin - при установке в выборе пакетов нужно найти и отметить всякие cmake, GDB и прочие, кем-нибудь рекомендуемые к установке. 
Сlion - File - Settings - Editor - File Encodings: IDE Encoding, Project Encoding, main.cpp (Ваш исполняемый файл) - UTF-8,
Default encoding for properties files - IBM866
В окне редактора внизу - UTF-8.

Включить заголовочный файл Windows.h

SetConsoleCP(866); SetConsoleOutputCP(866);

Answer (score 1):

Похоже вы компилируете проект с помощью MinGW, у меня была такая же проблема с кодировками в консоли СLion (которая выводится внизу при выборе "Run" в панели инструментов справа сверху), также пробовал разные кодировки, результат один не читаемые "крякозаблики". Правда когда используешь cp-1251 и запускаешь программу в консоли Windows (CMD), то тоже выводится всё хорошо (правда это не очень удобно, надо сделать больше телодвижений).

На другом ноутбуке попробовал использовать CLion вместе с CygWin и всё стало нормально при настройках кодировки по умолчанию, я использовал UTF-8.