# Кириллица в CLion

Tags: c++, кириллица, clion

Написал небольшое приложение

```
#include "iostream"
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int times = 0, start = 0, answ = 0;

template <typename T>
T fromString(const string& s)
{
    istringstream iss(s);
    T res;
    iss >> res;
    return res;
}

int InpInt(string s1)
{
    int i = 0, resultat;
    if (s1[0] == '-')
    {
        i++;
    }
    while (s1[i])
    {
        if ('0' <= s1[i] && s1[i] <= '9')
        {
            resultat = fromString<int>(s1);//перевод строки символов в int
        }
        else
        {
            resultat = 0;
            goto end;
        }
        i++;
    }
    end:
    return resultat;
}

int correctionInp(string s, int num_err)
{
    const string positiv_otv = "Нет", negative_otv = "Нет";
    string otv_user, inp_n, inp_el;
    int resultat;
    if (num_err == 1)
        cout << "Вы ошиблись при вводе значения переменной n" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Вы ошиблись при вводе значения элемента массива" << endl;
    cout << "Вы хотите ввести корректное значение?" << endl;
    cout << "Если Вы хотите изменить значение на корректное введите Да" << endl;
    cout << "Иначе, введите Нет" << endl;
    cout << "Ваш ответ: ";
    cin >> otv_user;
    if (otv_user == "Да")
    {
        if (num_err == 1)
        {
            cout << "Введите колчество строк и столбцов двумерного массива n. n > 0. n = " << endl;
            cin >> inp_n;
            resultat = InpInt(inp_n);
        }
        else
            cout << "Введите элемент массива" << endl;
        cin >> inp_el;
        resultat = InpInt(inp_el);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Вы точно хотите завершить программу?" << endl;
        cout << "Для завершения программы введите Да" << endl;
        if (num_err == 1)
        {
            cout << "Для изменения значения n введите Нет " << endl;
            cout << "Ваш ответ: ";
            cin >> otv_user;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Для изменеиня значения массива введите Нет ";
            cout << "Ваш ответ: ";
            cin >> otv_user;
        }
        if (otv_user == "Нет")
        {
            if (num_err == 1)
            {
                cout << "Введите колчество строк и столбцов двумерного массива n. n > 0. n = ";
                cin >> inp_n;
                resultat = InpInt(inp_n);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Введите значения элемента массива = ";
                cin >> inp_el;
                resultat = InpInt(inp_el);
                if ((inp_el != "0") && (resultat == 0))
                    resultat = -12345;
            }
        }
        else
            resultat = 0;
    }
    return resultat;
}

int search_min(int **A, int n) {
    int min = A[0][0];
    long start_time, end_time;
    start_time = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (min > A[i][j])
                min = A[i][j];
        }
    end_time = clock();
    times = end_time - start_time;
    return min;
}

int search_max(int **A, int n) {
    int max = A[0][0];
    long start_time = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (max < A[i][j])
                max = A[i][j];
        }
    long end_time = clock();
    times = end_time - start_time;
    return max;
}

int search_parallel_min(int **A, int n, int stream) {
    int min;
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(stream)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (min < A[i][j])
                min = A[i][j];
        }

    return min;
}

int search_parallel_max(int **A, int n, int stream) {
    int max;
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(stream)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (max < A[i][j])
                max = A[i][j];
        }
    times = clock();
    return max;
}

int main()
{

    string inp_el, inp_n;
    int n = 8, m, k = 0, num_err = 0, min, max;
    system("chcp 65001");
    //cout << "Здравствуйте, уважаемый Пользователь!" << endl;
    //cout << "Введите количество строк и столбцов двумерного массива n. n > 0. n = ";
    //cin >> inp_n;


    /*
    n = InpInt(inp_n);
    if ((n == 0) || (n < 0))
    {
        num_err = 1;
        n = correctionInp(inp_n, num_err);
        if (n == 0)
        {
            goto close;
        }
    }
    close:
    */
    int **A = new int *[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        A[j] = new int[n];

    if (n <= 5)
    {
        cout << "Введите элементы массива = ";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                cin >> inp_el;
                A[i][j] = InpInt(inp_el);
                if (((A[i][j] == 0) && (inp_el != "0")) || ((A[i][j] == 0) && (inp_el != "-0")) || ((A[i][j] == 0) && (inp_el != "+0")))
                {
                    num_err = 2;
                    A[i][j] = correctionInp(inp_n, num_err);
                }
            }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Массив будет введен с помощью генератора случайных чисел" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                A[i][j] = rand();
    }
    cout << "Вывод массива А" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (n > 15) {
                if (i == 9) {
                    cout << "..... " << "..... " << "..... " << "..... " << "..... " << "..... " << "..... " << "..... " << "..... " << "..... " << "..... " << "..... " << endl;
                    i = n - 2;
                    break;
                }
                cout << setw(5) << A[i][j] << " ";
                if (j == n - 1)
                    cout << endl;
                if (j == 9) {
                    cout << "..... " << setw(5) << A[i][n - 1] << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << setw(5) << A[i][j] << " ";
                if (j == n - 1)
                    cout << endl;
            }
        }
    start = clock();
    min = search_min(A, n);
    max = search_max(A, n);
    answ = clock();

    //min = search_parallel_min(A, n, n);
    //max = search_parallel_max(A, n, n);
    times = answ - start;

    cout << min << endl;
    cout << max << endl;
    cout << times << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Для отображения в консоли кириллицы использовал `system("chcp 65001");` При запуске программа не выдала вообще ничего. Просто попросила нажать на любую кнопку, чтобы завершить работу.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если не использовать переключение на кириллицу, то иероглифами, но программа будет выполняться[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Можете подсказать из-за чего такое происходит?

Comment: `65001` - это utf-8 кодировка. Попробуйте `system("chcp 1251");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLion` тут ни при чём. Измените кодировки исходников и консоли на `UTF-8` (или на нужную вам кодировку, поддерживающую русский язык, главное - чтобы она была одна везде, но лучше - `UTF-8`).

p.s.: не используйте `system`, используйте `<locale>`

p.p.s.: тем более это уже спрашивали много раз [Отображение кириллицы в CLion](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/449291/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-clion?rq=1)

Comment: Я запускал это через cmd exe файл с кодировкой UTF-8. Рещультат такой-же, как и в консоли,т.е. просто пишет о том, что включена кодировка utf-8 и просит нажать кнопку, чтобы завершить работу программы.

Answer (score 2):

Мне помогло для Windows:

```c
#include <windows.h>

// in main:
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вначале метода main допишите:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
```

Comment: ребята, давайте всё-таки придерживаться словаря C++ коль мы говорим об этом языке. метод - это виртуальная функция-член (member-function) класса. main это просто функция

Comment: кроме того в случае macOS и `std::cout` `std::wcout` это работать не будет